Why does this system of gcd equations have no solutions?
In February 2024 the following question was posed by user @Aig on Math.StackExchange:
Find the solutions to the system of equations $$\begin{cases} a + b = \gcd(a^3,b^3) \\ b+c = \gcd(b^3,c^3) \\ c+a = \gcd(c^3, a^3)\end{cases}$$
for positive integers $a,b,c$.
We checked ranges for $a,b,c$ with @Peter in one of the chatrooms upto $a,b,c \le 10^4$ with no solutions. It is conjectured this system has no solutions.
Despite being offered a bounty and multiple months passing, no conclusive answer was posted to the question. Some of the cases based on parities of $a,b,c$ were resolved still leaving other unresolved possibilities. I indicate some of the elementary progress made.
Consider $2(a+b+c) = \gcd(a,b)^3 + \gcd(b,c)^3 + \gcd(c,a)^3$. Considering the parity of $2$ on both sides, it follows that wlog $2 \mid a,b$. It can also be shown that $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $\gcd\left(b,\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\right) = \gcd\left(a,\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right) = 1$ etc. This gives that $c$ must be odd and that $\nu_2(a) = \nu_2(b)$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Maybe I'm being dense, but I can't even think of a solution to $a+b=\gcd(a^3,b^3)$. Do you have examples of $a$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfy 1 or 2 of the equalities?

$(a,b) = (2,6)$ works. More generally, $(a,b) = (k, k^3-k)$ for any $k \geq 2$. @Aeryk

A more general family of solutions: $(12, 15)$ and, more generally, $(ku, k^3-ku)$ for $\text{GCD}(k,u) = 1$.

If we ignore signs, then $(140, 203, -204)$ is a solution.

If we set $x=\gcd(b,c)$, $y=\gcd(a,c)$, $z=\gcd(a,b)$, then we necessarily have $a=(-x^3+y^3+z^3)/2$, $b=(x^3-y^3+z^3)/2$, $c=(x^3+y^3-z^3)/2$ (this follows from ioveri's answer on stackexchange and solving the system of linear equations for $a,b,c$). David Speyer's solution corresponds to $(x,y,z)=(-1,-4,7)$.

From this perspective, we are looking for pairwise coprime $x\leq y\leq z$ with $x\mid y^3-z^3$, $y\mid x^3-z^3$, $z\mid x^3-y^3$, and $x^3+y^3>z^3$. There seem to be plenty of solutions without the inequality constraint, but I don't see any particular reason why there couldn't be solutions that do satisfy the inequality constraint.

@ThomasBrowning's method is roughly how I found my example. Warning -- you need a little more than the divisibility condititions that he writes. If $x$ is odd, you need $x = \text{GCD}(x^3, y^3-z^3)$, if $x$ is even you need $2x = \text{GCD}(x^3, y^3-z^3)$. And the same with the variables permuted.

For what it’s worth: @Peter numerically investigated this system for exponents other than $3$. Up to $10^{11}$, we found two very large solution for the exponent $6$, but no solutions were found for other exponents $\le 10$ (except the exponent $2$, which has a trivial solution).

I searched for $1 \leq x < y < z \leq 10^3$ (which means $a$, $b$, $c$ up to roughly $10^9$) and found 14 solutions, but all of them have $c<0$. The smallest is $(x,y,z) = (1,4,9)$ and $(a,b,c) = (396,333,-332)$; the largest is $(x,y,z) = (71,91,730)$ and $(a,b,c) = (194706330, 194310670, -193952759)$. I would guess that there are solutions with $c>0$ and they are just large; that cone ${ x<y<z,\ x^3+y^3> z^3 }$ is pretty narrow.

There are 110 solutions (all with $c<0$) with $1\leq x<y<z\leq10^5$. (Pick $z$ first, precompute cube roots of unity $r$ mod $z$, run through $y<z$, and $x\equiv r*y\pmod{z}$).

@ThomasBrowning Interesting! I compute that, in the square $[0,z]^2$, 88.2% of the points have $x^3+y^3<z^3$ and 11.7% have $x^3+y^3 > z^3$. So it is a little surprising that, in 110 attempts, you didn't get one hit in that zone. Also, thanks for posting your progress! That's a lot more than my poor Mathematica script could get through, so I'll stop searching unless I have a really good idea for how to improve efficiency.

@ThomasBrowning One thing that I noticed -- there are a fair number of solutions where either $z \equiv x \bmod y$ or $z \equiv y \bmod x$. For such a solution, $z \geq x+y$ so $z^3 \geq (x+y)^3 > x^3+y^3$. But it's only 6 out of my first 20 solutions.

@ThomasBrowning In my data range, I have no solutions with $z < x+y$. Is that also true for you? Maybe the stronger inequality $z>x+y$ holds, which would imply $z^3>x^3+y^3$.

Yes, $y$ is rarely close to $z$, and even then, $x$ is too small. The "best" I've gotten is $(x,y,z)=(5024,226325,257749)$.

Little update: I've been searching for solutions with $0<x<y<z$ and $z-y<x$ by iterating over $x$ and $t=z-y<x$ and $y\mid x^3-t^3$. If my code is correct, there are no solutions with $x\leq10^5$ (whereas before I had searched up to $z\leq10^5$).

Thanks for the updates. I'm thinking of putting a bounty soon on this question to bring more attention and possible proof/counterexample..

@DavidESpeyer's family $(ku, k^3-ku)$ covers all solutions to $a+b = \gcd(a^3, b^3)$ but that doesn't seem to be explicitly stated yet in this comment thread.

The bounty will end in 3 days. I'm willing to reward to even partial answers-- its best if it doesnt go to waste. Thanks.

With a appropriate definition of gcd, this seems to have solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all prime $p$ and even $a=b=c=1/2$ is such a solution in $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{2}]$. This may indicate why it is not an easy question.

This is a partial answer summarizing the progress that was made in the comments (plus results from further numerical searching). If we set $x=\gcd(b,c)$, $y=\gcd(a,c)$, and $z=\gcd(a,b)$, then we can solve the system of linear equations for $a$, $b$, and $c$, giving
\begin{align*}
a&=(-x^3+y^3+z^3)/2,\\
b&=(x^3-y^3+z^3)/2,\\
c&=(x^3+y^3-z^3)/2.
\end{align*}
So we can instead search for pairwise coprime $0<x<y<z$ satisfying certain constraints. For instance, they must satisfy $x\mid z^3-y^3$, $y\mid z^3-x^3$, $z\mid y^3-x^3$, and $x^3+y^3>z^3$.
As David Speyer points out, there are also additional gcd conditions that must be satisfied in order for $(x,y,z)$ to give rise to a valid solution $(a,b,c)$.
Here is some numerical data:

There are $3990$ tuples $(x,y,z)$ of pairwise coprime $0<x<y<z\leq10^6$ that satisfy $x\mid z^3-y^3$, $y\mid z^3-x^3$, and $z\mid y^3-x^3$.
Of these $3990$ tuples $(x,y,z)$, only $271$ satisfy the additional gcd conditions that David Speyer mentions. These $271$ tuples $(x,y,z)$ give rise to solutions $(a,b,c)$ with $c$ negative.
Of these $271$ tuples, only $(x,y,z)=(172081,206896,347985)$ satisfies $x+y>z$, and none satisfy $x^3+y^3>z^3$.
Note that these values $x=172081=7 \times 13 \times 31 \times 61$, $y=206896=2^4 \times 67 \times 193$, and $z=347985=3^2 \times 5 \times 11 \times 19 \times 37$ have lots of $1\text{ mod }3$ prime factors because that makes it easier to have the required collisions $y^3\equiv z^3\pmod{x}$, $x^3\equiv z^3\pmod{y}$, and $x^3\equiv y^3\pmod{z}$.

The $3990$ tuples can be found here: https://pastebin.com/G7LE7Qyd
The $271$ tuples can be found here: https://pastebin.com/1xZ2ZKZT
And here is a scatterplot of $(x/z,y/z)$ with the $3990$ tuples in black and the $271$ tuples in red:


I've computationally verified that a solution (if exists) should have $x > 10^4$.

Nice summary, thanks! I edited in the factorization of the integers in the last bullet point. At this point, I have no opinion as to whether or not solutions with $x^3+y^3 > z^3$ exist or not.

If you feel like making a graphic, I think it might be interesting to see a scatterplot of the 230 points $(x/z, y/z)$ in the unit square $[0,1]^2$, with the curves $x/z+y/z=1$ and $(x/z)^3 + (y/z)^3 =1$ drawn on it. If you upload the 230 points, I can make the plot. Seeing where the 3261 points are might be interesting too.

@MaxAlekseyev I've also searched $x\leq10^5$.

@DavidESpeyer I've added a scatterplot, but feel free to replace if you have a way of making one that looks nicer.

@ThomasBrowning Thanks! Looks good to me.

Was any progress made on this after? Is there any "reasonable" guess as to whether there may be some very large solution, or it has no solutions at all?

I did a little more searching without finding anything interesting. My guess is that there are solutions, just very large.

This is not a complete proof as it uses a conjecture claimed in this question.

Any solution of $a+b=\text{gcd}(a^3,b^3)$ is of the form $(ku, k^3-ku)$ for coprime integers $k$ and $u$ (discussed by David and Peter in the comments). Hence, by solving the system:
$$k_2u_2=k_1^3-k_1u_1 \\
k_3u_3=k_2^3-k_2u_2 \\
k_1u_1=k_3^3-k_3u_3 \tag{1}$$
with respect to $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$, the problem in the OP becomes equivalent to find a positive integral solution for the following system of Diophantine equations:
$$2k_1u_1=k_1^3-k_2^3+k_3^3 \\
2k_2u_2=k_1^3+k_2^3-k_3^3 \\
2k_3u_3=-k_1^3+k_2^3+k_3^3, \tag{2}$$
which also satisfies the coprime condition:
$$\text{gcd}(k_1,u_1)=\text{gcd}(k_2,u_2)=\text{gcd}(k_3,u_3)=1. \tag{3}$$
Assume that $u_1,u_2,u_3$ and $k_1,k_2,k_3$ is a positive solution of (2) that satisfies (3). Using the conjecture claimed here for (2), we have $\text{gcd}(k_1,k_2,k_3)=d>1$. However, the coprime condition (3) implies that $d^2|k_1,k_2,k_3$ for $d=2$ and $d^3|k_1,k_2,k_3$ for $d>2$, which contradicts $\text{gcd}(k_1,k_2,k_3)=d$.

I think something might have gone wrong between the first triple of displayed equations and the second triple? If I solve the first linear system for the $u$'s, I get $2 u_1 = \frac{k_1^3+k_2^3-k_3^3}{k_1}$, not $2 u_1 = k_1^2 + k_2^2 - k_3^2$.

@DavidESpeyer Thanks! I fixed the error. The correct one is $2k_1u_1=k_1^3-k_2^3+k_3^3$.
